# Как подключить рекламу от Яндекса в Unity?

Tags: unity3d, реклама, встроенная-реклама

Пытаюсь подключить рекламу от Яндекса в своё приложение в магазине.

1. В РСЯ добавил своё приложение (как они просили). Оно прошло модерацию
2. Для него добавил рекламный блок (полно-экранная реклама)
3. Теперь Яндекс пишет, что нужно "Подключить рекламный блок к приложению"
   и предлагает несколько вариантов.

Я предполагаю, что мне подходит:  "Прямая интеграция с Yandex Mobile Ads SDK".
Я согласен с тем, что в приложении будут показаны объявления только из Рекламной сети Яндекса.

И тогда у меня 3 варианта:

1)Подключение Yandex Mobile Ads SDK для Android

2)Подключение Yandex Mobile Ads SDK для iOS

3)Подключение Mobile Ads Unity плагина

Вопрос: мне нужен 1 вариант  "Подключение Yandex Mobile Ads SDK для Android (т.к. программа для андроида)?

Или нужен 3 вариант  "Подключение Mobile Ads Unity плагина" (т.к. пишу на Unity)?

Или 1 и 3 варианты одновременно?

Делаю это в первый раз. Поэтому без помощи не могу разобраться.
Остановился на этом шаге. Подскажите, как правильно поступить?

Answer (score -1):

Яндекс реклама есть дружит с юнити, глянь интеграцию и все. Там совмещенка андроида и аиос. С юнити адс ты замучаешь с выводом и выбором банка для вывода средств.

Ссылка на интеграцию: https://yandex.ru/dev/mobile-ads/doc/plugins/unity/quick-start/init.html